# jQuery/JSON/PHP failing

Tags: php, jquery, json

I am trying to call a php script that accepts JSON data, writes it into a file and returns simple text response using jQuery/AJAX call.

jQuery code :

```
   $("input.callphp").click(function() {
    var url_file = myurl;
    $.ajax({type : "POST",
            url : url_file,
            data : {puzzle: 'Reset!'},
            success : function(data){
                alert("Success");
                alert(data);
            }, 
            error : function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert("Error: " + textStatus + "<" + errorThrown + ">");
            },
            dataType : 'text'
    });
});
```

PHP Code :

```
<?php
  $thefile = "new.json"; /* Our filename as defined earlier */
  $towrite = $_POST["puzzle"]; /* What we'll write to the file */
  $openedfile = fopen($thefile, "w");
  fwrite($openedfile, $towrite);
  fclose($openedfile);
  echo "<br> <br>".$towrite;
?>
```

However, the call is never a success and always gives an error with an alert "Error : [Object object]".

#### NOTE

This code works fine. I was trying to perform a cross domain query - I uploaded the files to the same server and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

```
var url_file = myurl"; // remove `"` from end
```

Arguments of `error` function is:

```
.error( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown )
```

not `data`,

You can get `data` (ie. response data from server) as `success()` function argument.

Like:

```
success: function(data) {

}
```

For more info look **[.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)**

#### NOTE

If you're trying to get data from cross-domain (i.e from different domain), then you need `jsonp` request.

Comment: `success: function(data) { ... }` is perfectly valid.

Comment: Yes, but you said (before your edit) that the arguments are _not_ `data`, which is incorrect.

Comment: @JamWaffles I told that for `.error()`, anyway thanks Sir, for your comment

Comment: Ah, so you did, my apologies.

Comment: #thecodeparadox : thanks for the reply. I have updated the code after making the suggestions, however, i am still getting an error alert "Error: error<>".

Comment: @user730936 what does alert within success function display? It would  be better if you use `console.log(data)` within success function ans see the result with firebug/such debugger

Comment: #thecodeparadox, Would it even be calling the success callback as the call is failing and error callback is being called? I'm using firebug and added the line, nothing gets logged.

Answer (score 0):

Your `data` object isn't valid; the key shouldn't be quoted:

```
data : { puzzle: 'Reset!' }
```

---

In addition, SO's syntax highlighting points out that you have missed out a `"` in your code:

```
var url_file = myurl";
```

Should be

```
var url_file = "myurl;
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. I have updated the data object (edited the original post). But, I am still getting an error alert "Error: error<>".